# How can we test connection resiliency in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've turned on connection resiliency in Entity Framework Core:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>( options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configurations["ConnectionString"]),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
        maxRetryCount: 10,
        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    });
```

Now I would like to create some unit test to prove this is actually working.
Is it possible to do something like that?

The `InMemoryDbContext` doesn't seem to have the `EnableRetryOnFailure` method and the most similar test I could find was in EF6:
https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/testing-out-the-connection-resiliency-feature-into-ef6/

(and it's kinda complex to follow)

As some additional info i'm using SQL server 2017 and Entity Framework Core 2.2.0, when testing manually if I take the database offline it fails instantly.

Am i testing it wrong or i'm missing something to set this up properly?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to test? Probe the connectionstring with `dbContext.Database.Exists()` Are you questioning that the EF feature for retries is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am questioning if EF feature works correctly, manually testing it it seems to not to be working

Comment: More context will be needed, like what dbms and version is used. Where does it fail and what is the exception. Consider refering to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues as you will probably rather get support.

Comment: If by "taking the database offline" you literally mean setting the database state to `OFFLINE`, the failure is expected -- that's not one of the conditions resiliency guards against, as it is not a transient condition that would most likely resolve itself in time. If the server is up but the database was explicitly set offline, you'll immediately get that back as an error -- adding retry for that, if desired, is up to your application. To test connection resiliency, you have to take down the server itself -- i.e. shut down SQL Server (or firewall port 1433, same effect).

Comment: Incidentallly, the `errorNumbersToAdd` property should allow you to mark "database is offline" as a transient error, if so desired -- the error number is 942. Use this only if it makes sense in production as well -- otherwise, for testing, it makes more sense to add 50000, the error number of a custom `RAISERROR` (e.g. `RAISERROR('This is a transient error!', 11, 0)`), which is easy to inject in queries. Don't use that in production either, of course, since most custom errors should not be blindly retried -- it makes more sense to use something like Polly for that.

Comment: the error was actually 4060 and not 942, but yes that was the way to go and to notice i am actually enabling connection resiliency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeroen Mostert answered this in the comments:

> If by "taking the database offline" you literally mean setting the
> database state to OFFLINE, the failure is expected -- that's not one
> of the conditions resiliency guards against, as it is not a transient
> condition that would most likely resolve itself in time. If the server
> is up but the database was explicitly set offline, you'll immediately
> get that back as an error -- adding retry for that, if desired, is up
> to your application. To test connection resiliency, you have to take
> down the server itself -- i.e. shut down SQL Server (or firewall port
> 1433, same effect).
>
> Incidentallly, the errorNumbersToAdd property should allow you to mark
> "database is offline" as a transient error, if so desired -- the error
> number is 942. Use this only if it makes sense in production as well
> -- otherwise, for testing, it makes more sense to add 50000, the error number of a custom RAISERROR (e.g. RAISERROR('This is a transient
> error!', 11, 0)), which is easy to inject in queries. Don't use that
> in production either, of course, since most custom errors should not
> be blindly retried -- it makes more sense to use something like Polly
> for that.

That seems to be the best explanation.